# Window confirm redirects even on cancel

Tags: javascript, jquery, symfony, twig

I've got a problem.

I have this window confirm:

```
<td>
  <span>
    <a onClick="return confirm('Opravdu si přejete odebrat školu z oblíbených?');" href="{{    path('parent/school/remove', {'school_id': school.id}) }}"> 
       <i class="fa fa-times-circle fa-2x"></i>
    </a> 
    {{school.name}}
  </span>
</td>
```

But whether i click on Ok, or on Cancel, it will still proc the link in the href attribute and redirect to this action.

Answer (score 3):

Do it like this:

```
<a onclick="confirm('Leave?') || event.preventDefault()" href="http://en.wikipedia.org">Wikipedia</a>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/5s47wujv/

Comment: @user1999739 - Are you sure you entered correctly? Does the demo in my answer work?

Comment: This does not stops browser's tab close event. (I think @user1999739 want to stop it too)

Comment: @ThanasisGrammatopoulos There is no "close" event. All I did is cancelled the "click" event.

Comment: I think @user1999739 is also asking for an implementation of the window.onbeforeunload event as he say "when i click on X button in browser".

Comment: I need to prevent redirect on <a href > action when i click cancel for example.

Comment: The problem is, when i understand it correctly, preventDefault should prevent this <a> tag to redirect to href action, unfortunately it does not, and when i click on this link, it still redirects whether i click on ok or on cancel.

Comment: @ThanasisGrammatopoulos I believe he is not looking for a solution that uses `beforeunload` since it will prompt at *every* unload event, even if the link isn't clicked. By "X" I believe he means the close button in the `confirm` modal.

Comment: Exactly as Derek said :)

Comment: Ok but please fix the question.

Comment: Genius! It helped in my case - when I had to redirect to a different page after the confirmation.